# Background color/image bug when using [margin: 0 auto;] on inner div

Tags: css, background, margin

In my example (link below) some of the background of the OUTER DIV magically disappears when the browser size goes smaller than the defined width of the INNER DIV (960px). The horizontal scrollbar kicks in, as expected, but when you scroll to the right you don't get to see the missing section of the image. I believe it has something to do with the INNER DIV's property of [margin: 0 auto;], because when the INNER DIV is taken out of the code, the OUTER DIV's background shows as it should (it gets cutoff, but no scroll bar).

Anyone have any ideas why this is happening...and how to fix it?:

http://ryanderson.com/stackoverflow/background/

Comment: Dear see my answer and let me know if i am lagging some where....

Answer (score 1):

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<title>CSS Background Problem</title>
<style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="outer">
<div id="inner"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Css:

```
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#outer {
    background: url("background-picture.jpg") no-repeat scroll center top transparent;
    height: 500px;
}
#inner {
    background: url("diagonal-lines.png") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply - but this code does not fix the problem. The same thing happens (background-picture.jpg partially disappears when the browser goes smaller than 960px wide).